# How to use a . in a ASP .NET Web Api route, e.g.; domain.com/api/users.get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need help,how to call an API method using point as method qualifier?

Some examples::

- `domain.com/api/users.create?name=smt`
- `domain.com/api/users.get?name=smt`
- `domain.com/api/users.ban?id=smt`

And others. I tried to explore the internet on same issues,but have not found any.

Comment: Create should be a post, without query string. Further; what is your question? Calling an API can be done dozens of ways (browser, postman, javascript, httpclient, etc.)

Comment: I want to call api like domain.com/api/users.get?id=543&name=qwerty, so method quaifier shoul be point(.)

Comment: so url should be like domain.com/api/users.get,not domain.com/api/users/get

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll change your title, it was a bit confusing ;-)